# How do I draw a dot or a point in visual c++ and write next to it?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to draw a thick point or a dot in the client area of an mfc alpplication. Is there a function to do so? Alternatively I could even draw an extremely small circle and fill it with a colour to make it appear as a dot- but again how do I fill an object? especially a curved one?
    Then I also want to put some text next to it- so what function could i use to "write" in the client area?

Comment: You really need a book on Windows programming. That said, you can draw a dot with `Ellipse` and text with `TextOut` or `DrawText`. With MFC, those will be [`pDC->Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hkxb3kd.aspx), [`pDC->TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yzabsdzx.aspx) and [`pDC->DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a6x7y2a4.aspx). Note that you normally want to do all drawing in your view class's `OnDraw`.

Answer (score 1):

```
GetDC()->SetPixel(x, y, RGB(1,2,3))
```

Where GetDC() will return the current CWnd's device context, (x,y) are the coordinates, and RGB() is the red/greed/blue color.

Look at GetDC()->Ellipse() for a circle, etc. and GetDC()->TextOut() for displaying text.

It would be good to become familiar with device contexts in general, see:

[MFC CDC Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acfw2ha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)